# Push Notifications with Ionic 2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, ionic2

I am trying to set up **Push Notifications** with **Ionic 2**.

I believe I need to set up **Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)**. However, every tutorial I look at seems out of date, even pretty recent ones including [this **Ionic 2** one](https://docs.ionic.io/services/profiles/#android-gcm-project--api-key). I think Google have changed their service to rather use **Firebase**.

Does anyone have reference to a tutorial that explains how to set up **GCM** with **Ionic 2** please?  Or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can still use the [GCM Setup Guide for Ionic](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#setup) but now, you need to add in the [Migration Guide](https://docs.ionic.io/migration.html) to know the updates or the changes that you also need to implement. Anyways, the latest version of GCM is FCM, but GCM is still currently supported.

Additionally, you can refer to these helpful links if you wish to migrate from GCM to FCM:

- [Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)
- [GCM and FCM Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq)

Lastly, this related SO post - [Setup for Ionic Cloud using FCM now that GCM not available for new projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300425/setup-for-ionic-cloud-using-fcm-now-that-gcm-not-available-for-new-projects) might also help.

Comment: Thank you.  I also saw this which may be useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653251/firebase-cloud-messaging-with-ionic-app